# Django norel access to different nosql at the same time?

Tags: django, mongodb, cassandra, django-nonrel, nosql

i'm new to the nosql world, and from forums and articles that i've read: most of users try to "mix" nosql tools, for example, they use Cassandra and MongoDB together to make a "powerful system", because am beginning with MongoDB, i've downloaded the [DjanMon](https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon) project (am a django fan ^_^ ), of course i've downloaded the special version of django that accepts the NoSql use: [Django NonRel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), and i've noticed that the Setting file dont "oblige" you to use one specific NoSql solution like in Django with RDBMS where you must specify MySql or PostegreSql or other solution, so, is it possible to mix lot of (or two of course) NoSql solution using Django (for example MongoDB+Cassandra)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing to *stop* you using multiple storage solutions, whether SQL or NoSQL - but the NoSQL solutions all have different architectures, data models and APIs (For example, MongoDB is a document-oriented database, whereas Cassandra is Column-oriented), so you can't usually swap one for another without some effort.

Can you clarify what you are actually trying to achieve? I.e. why are you interested in mixing these two specific solutions?

Comment: hi,
thank you for the reply,
yes, as you said, because nosql has different architecture, so i said that maybe i can use key-based architecture to fetch the "documents" of mongodb? or did i misunderstood something?